# How to extract only the last name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I created this table:

```
create table customers
(
        code              varchar(7),
        fullname          varchar(9),

CONSTRAINT pk_codreparacion PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

I inserted this dates:

```
insert into customers(code, fullname) 
values('001','John Smith');
insert into customers(code, fullname) 
values('002','William Thorne');
insert into customers(code, fullname) 
values('003','Mark Johanson');
```

The question is: as I can get only the last names with consultations in mysql ?. ie, John Smith = ' Smith '

Comment: Have you heard about [substring_index](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)?

Comment: As Raju said use  `substring_index`, but if you are creating your table include two fields `FirstName` and `LastName`

Comment: Are you guaranteed that full name always  consists of two words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't without mistakes**

Names are not always as simple as your examples :

- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names.en
- http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

But if you have a column with **two words separated by a space** you can use substring_index as said in the comments ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index )

Comment: Thank you very much, i use this query: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( fullname, ' ', -1 ) from customers and I get the last name.  Only it works with two words